# How can I configure Sendmail to use the From address as the envelope sender?

Tags: sendmail, return-path

My Sendmail is using `daemon-user@internal.hostname.example.com` as the envelope sender on messages my server generates using `/usr/bin/sendmail`.  I want it to get the address from the `From:` header in the message and use that instead.

I'm not currently using the `-f` option to `sendmail`, and I'd rather not have to change the code to do that.  It uses a few different from addresses, so I can't just set it to a constant value.  Also, using `-f` adds a `X-Authentication-Warning:` header that I don't want.

Is there some way to configure Sendmail to use the From address as the envelope sender?  This server can only be accessed by trusted users, so I'm not worried about bogus addresses.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such sendmail's command line option.

You may use sendmail wrapper script/program to fix your problem.  Does your code accepts custom sendmail's path?

You may use `FEATURE(use_ct_file)` *in submit.mc* to stop sendmail from generating `X-Authentication-Warning:` for users listed in `/etc/mail/trusted-users` file.